# Undefined $(this) on nested functions

Tags: javascript, jquery

So basically I have two functions on my `click()` trigger.

```
var firstFunction = function() {
    var id = $(this).attr('id');
    alert(id);
};

var secondFunction = function() {
    //something here
};

$('#trigger').click(function() {
    firstFunction();
    secondFunction();
});
```

On `firstFunction()` I'm trying to get `$(this).attr('id')` but it's returning `undefined`.

I know it has something two do with calling multiple functions because it works when I only call one function

```
$('#trigger').click(firstFunction);
```

Sample [Fiddle here](https://jsfiddle.net/poq2xhbc/)

Comment: https://jsfiddle.net/satpalsingh/84hpwyhv/

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As per your existing approach `this` refers to `Window` object not the element which invoke the event.

You can use [`.bind()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_objects/Function/bind)

> The `bind()` method creates a new function that, when called, has its `this` keyword set to the provided value,

```
$('#trigger').click(function() {
    firstFunction.bind(this)();
    secondFunction.bind(this)();
})
```

```js
var firstFunction = function() {
    var id = $(this).attr('id');
    console.log(id);
};

var secondFunction = function() {
    //something here
    var id = $(this).attr('id');
    console.log(id);
};

$('#trigger').click(function() {
    firstFunction.bind(this)();
    secondFunction.bind(this)();
})
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<button id="trigger">Click Me</button>
```

[**Fiddle**](https://jsfiddle.net/satpalsingh/84hpwyhv/)

Answer (score 1):

It's returning undefined because you aren't applying the same `this` as the event. You can achieve this by using `call` or `apply` instead of calling it directly.

```
$('#trigger').click(function() {
    firstFunction.call(this);
    secondFunction.call(this);
});
```

Answer (score 1):

The `this` inside the `firstFunction` will be the *window* object itself - pass `this` to the function to *fix* it - see demo below:

```js
var firstFunction = function(el) {
  var id = $(el).attr('id');
  alert(id);
};

var secondFunction = function() {
  //something here
};

$('#trigger').click(function() {
  firstFunction(this);
  secondFunction(this);
})
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<button id="trigger">Click Me</button>
```

Another way is to use [`Function.prototype.call`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Function/call) to bind a `this` argument to the funciton:

```js
var firstFunction = function() {
  var id = $(this).attr('id');
  alert(id);
};

var secondFunction = function() {
  //something here
};

$('#trigger').click(function() {
  firstFunction.call(this);
  secondFunction.call(this);
})
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<button id="trigger">Click Me</button>
```

Answer (score 1):

You can pass the jQuery object element and than only use it in your function:

```js
var firstFunction = function($el) {
    var id = $el.attr('id');
    console.log(id);
};

var secondFunction = function() {
    //something here
};

$('#trigger').click(function() {
    firstFunction($(this));
    secondFunction();
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<button id="trigger">Button</button>
```

Answer (score 1):

`click()` handler receives event as parameter. Pass it because `this` is not available in the scope of `firstFunction()`.

Like this:

```
var firstFunction = function(target) {
    var id = $(target).attr('id');
    alert(id);
};

var secondFunction = function() {
    //something here
};

$('#trigger').click(function(e) {
    firstFunction(e.target);
    secondFunction();
});
```

Answer (score 0):

Nothing to do major, it's quite simple.

If you are calling a function and into that function you need an event to be used, then pass a reference in the function parameter.

I have updated the code in your Fiddle and updated with Mine:

**Step 1:**

```
$('#trigger').click(function(event) {
  var that = this;
  firstFunction(that);
  secondFunction(that);
});
```

Created a variable **that** assigned this to that and passed into function parameter.

Note that, writing **event** in the click function is required to define this as a local click reference (Not a window)

**Step 2:**

Passed **that** rather than this, to make sure the reference is from click function only not of window.

```
var firstFunction = function(that) {
  var id = $(that).attr('id');
  alert(id);
};
```

[Updated Fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/krunal2450/poq2xhbc/1/)